# All \ttfamily font change font size

Tags: fontsize, typewriter

`\documentclass[11pt]{book}`

This code shows default font size.
I want to change font size all \ttfamily font in document (only for \ttfamily font). Other fonts not change.

How can I do?
Thanks,

Comment: What do you want to change it to?

Comment: \ttfamily show bigger than default font.

Answer (score 4):

You can update the definition of `\ttfamily` to include the font changes that you need. For example, below `\ttfamily` has been updated to always use `\LARGE` (say). Here is the default definition of `\ttfamily` from [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx):

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\ttfamily
        {\not@math@alphabet\ttfamily\mathtt
         \fontfamily\ttdefault\selectfont}
```

Here is an updated version in the form of a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\makeatletter
% Definition of \ttfamily from latex.ltx
\DeclareRobustCommand\ttfamily
        {\not@math@alphabet\ttfamily\mathtt
         \fontfamily\ttdefault\LARGE\selectfont}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Some normal text.

{\ttfamily Some typewriter text.\par}

Some normal and \texttt{typewriter} text.
\end{document}
```

The above example also shows why this should not be done.

Answer (score 4):

The most reliable way is to change the font definitions, applying a magnification factor. I'll do it for the T1 encoding, with a magnification factor of 1.1. Below the similar code for the OT1 encoding.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
\expandafter\let\csname T1/cmtt/m/n/10.95\endcsname\relax
\begingroup
\nfss@catcodes
\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{cmtt}{\hyphenchar \font\m@ne}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{cmtt}{m}{n}{
        <-9>    s*[1.1] ectt0800
        <9-10>  s*[1.1] ectt0900
        <10-12> s*[1.1] ectt1000
        <12-17> s*[1.1] ectt1200
        <17->   s*[1.1] ectt1728
      }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{cmtt}{m}{it}{
        <-9>    s*[1.1] ecit0800
        <9-10>  s*[1.1] ecit0900
        <10-12> s*[1.1] ecit1000
        <12-17> s*[1.1] ecit1200
        <17->   s*[1.1] ecit1728
      }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{cmtt}{m}{sl}{
        <-9>    s*[1.1] ecst0800
        <9-10>  s*[1.1] ecst0900
        <10-12> s*[1.1] ecst1000
        <12-17> s*[1.1] ecst1200
        <17->   s*[1.1] ecst1728
      }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{cmtt}{m}{sc}{
        <-9>    s*[1.1] ectc0800
        <9-10>  s*[1.1] ectc0900
        <10-12> s*[1.1] ectc1000
        <12-17> s*[1.1] ectc1200
        <17->   s*[1.1] ectc1728
      }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{cmtt}{bx}{n}
       {<->sub  cmtt/m/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{cmtt}{bx}{it}
       {<->sub  cmtt/m/it}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{cmtt}{bx}{sl}
       {<->sub  cmtt/m/sl}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{cmtt}{b}{n}
       {<->sub  cmtt/m/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{cmtt}{b}{it}
       {<->sub  cmtt/m/it}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{cmtt}{b}{sl}
       {<->sub  cmtt/m/sl}{}
\endgroup
\makeatother

\begin{document}
abc\texttt{def}ghi

\fontencoding{OT1}\selectfont
abc\texttt{def}ghi
\end{document}
```

The second line is just to show the difference with the original appearance. Apply the magnification factor you think best.

[image]

If you prefer sticking with OT1, then you should use the following code:

```
\makeatletter
\begingroup
\nfss@catcodes
\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{cmtt}{\hyphenchar \font\m@ne}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmtt}{m}{n}{
        <-9>    s*[1.1] cmtt8
        <9-10>  s*[1.1] cmtt9
        <10-12> s*[1.1] cmtt10
        <12->   s*[1.1] cmtt12
      }{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmtt}{m}{it}{
        <->     s*[1.1] cmitt10
      }{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmtt}{m}{sl}{
        <->     s*[1.1] cmsltt10
      }{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmtt}{m}{sc}{
        <->     s*[1.1] cmtcsc10
      }{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmtt}{m}{ui}
       {<->ssub*cmtt/m/it}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmtt}{bx}{n}
       {<->ssub*cmtt/m/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmtt}{bx}{it}
       {<->ssub*cmtt/m/it}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmtt}{bx}{ui}
       {<->ssub*cmtt/m/it}{}
\endgroup
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are willing to change the font, you can use a scalable font for ttfamily.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled=0.8]{beramono}

\begin{document}
abc\texttt{def}ghi

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty hack for inline typewriter font:

`\newcommand{\texttx}[1]{{\small \texttt{#1}}}`

Comment: Nice first answer, it could be improved by making it a small complete example starting with `\documentclass{article}` or similar and ending with `\end{document}`, even better would be with a picture so future readers can see the output, helps keep the site clean and is very helpful for future readers who might use your solution :)